# Facing issues with react installation using the command npx create-react-app my-app on macOS

Tags: reactjs

when i am running the command npx create-react-app my-app it is starting to install but then the following error is showing.

Creating a new React app in /Users/amareshsahoo/Desktop/writesc/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall link
npm ERR! path /Users/amareshsahoo/.npm/_cacache/tmp/0a1653e1
npm ERR! dest /Users/amareshsahoo/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/ed/af/5adc3d64e140952a72e1ae000bc8570fed80ac2ce408c4f77474a8dfffa1ae3dc8328863fbd1ec167421ab48aedebf28729a2d2a3b812a0a6489a1f0de63
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/amareshsahoo/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/amareshsahoo/.npm/_logs/2023-07-30T04_48_11_790Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from /Users/amareshsahoo/Desktop/writesc
Done.
```

This is the error i am getting . How to sort this issue.i am using the latest 18.x version of node

i tried lowering the version of node.js still the issue persisted. i tried running it as admin still it did not work.

Comment: Not sure if this is safe to do but the error message says that you can run `sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/amareshsahoo/.npm` to fix the issue. I am not sure what user has ID `501` and what group has ID `20`. I would recommend that you uninstall node and npm completely and install it back using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and you probably won't have to worry about these permissions issues.